# Location Sensitive Web Site Splash Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I need to organise my companies websites so that depending on the location of a user they get redirected to a country specific version of the site e.g.

- US Users get redirected to a US
  specific page
- UK users get redirected
  to a UK specific page.

I've seen this done plenty of times but am not sure how its implemented. I'm thinking some sort of IP address lookup?

Basically I want to know how to achieve this and if there are any .NET/C#/JavaScript utilities that could assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normally done via IP lookups - this is called GeoIP, or [Geo Locating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_targeting).

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947172/what-is-the-best-provider-of-geoip-data) - asking for good providers that are cost effective.

Answer (score 4):

Check http://www.hostip.info/

The have an IP lookup service.

You could also use the accept-locale request header... but it can be misleading.